# Multiple Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating multiple activities in Android. When I run the app, it can't connect to other activities so just wondering. These are my code, I have 3 xml files and 3 java files.

This is logcat log file.

log.txt

```
05-03 01:57:10.335: E/PhonePolicy(23020): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
05-03 01:57:12.665: W/dalvikvm(23020): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409db1f8)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jumoun.itemp/com.jumoun.itemp.Temperature}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4427)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at com.jumoun.itemp.Temperature.<init>(Temperature.java:14)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
05-03 01:57:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(23020):    ... 11 more
05-03 01:57:14.115: I/Process(23020): Sending signal. PID: 23020 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you add your Activities to your Manifest?

Comment: What is at line 14 if `Temperature`? Something is `null` most likely you are trying to access a `View` that isn't in the inflated `layout`

Comment: @Tom if that were the case then the OP would have a different exception

Comment: Please post your java code along with xml code.

Comment: Tom, Yes I already added activites in Manifest, when I run Java, there is no Java error. 

codeMagic, Temperature is the class, Temperature.java, I already declare as .Temperature in Manifest.

shree202, ok

This is my java code.
http://pastebin.com/R7AEWExX

Comment: I understand that `Temperature` is the class. The logcat shows that something at line 14 in `Temperature` is `null`. That is the code that we need to see along with the associated xml. Again, "Something is null most likely you are trying to access a View that isn't in the inflated layout"

Comment: Is the `Temperature` class an `Activity`?

Comment: post code of Temperature.java file

Comment: @codeMagic, ok I will show you :)
Gustek, this is the code :)

Temperature.java
http://pastebin.com/t9Hu2zJx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to set your `views` inside a method after you call `setContentView()`. These

```
ImageButton ibHome2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibHome2);
    Button bTempConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTempConvert);
    EditText etCel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCel);
    EditText etFah = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFah);
```

should be here

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.temperature);

        ImageButton ibHome2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibHome2);
        Button bTempConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTempConvert);
        EditText etCel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCel);
        EditText etFah = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFah);
```

Your `views` exist within your `layout` so you can try to access them with `findViewById()` before you inflate your `layout` by calling `setContentView()` or through using an `inflater` otherwise they will return `null` since your `layout` doesn't exist yet

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept one of the answers if they helped so others may find them easier

Comment: Hi, I still face problem, this is my Converter.java code, I still can't connect to it :( http://pastebin.com/VNNPy7D5

Comment: It says it needs 15 reputation that is why I can't click on both of you guys. You guys are correct :)

Comment: You can't upvote but you can accept by clicking the check mark. I don't see anything obvious so I can't tell you the problem unless I know what the error is. If its related then I can try to help you here. If it is an unrelated problem (different error) then post a new question with relevant code and error messages

Comment: Ok uncle, I already clicked check mark :) Btw can you help me? I can't connect to that Converter.java now, from my Home.java class :(

Comment: See my previous comment. If you post a new question you can let me know and I will look. But I would need to see `converter` class, the part of `temperature` where you try to call it and error messages/logcat

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `findViewById()` in class scope,

this method may not be called before `setContentView()` method, if You call it in class scope it will be called on object creation so way before `onCreate()` where You inflate layout.

Move calls to `findViewById()` to `onCreate()`.

Comment: I see, I will try it first :)